# Need help to explain a line of Opencv/Numpy code

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone please explain to me what would the following line do?

```
bgr = img[:,:,:3]
```

Comment: That copies all of the first and second dimensions, but only the first 3 elements of the 3rd dimension.  If you had a (5,5,5) array, you would end up with a (5,5,3) array.  Imagine if you had an image that was a (640,480,3) array; img[:,:,:2] would keep the R and G values, but not the B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to look for here is "slicing" and "indexing". Have a look on those links:

- https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html
- https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp

Basically, `img` is a 3-dimensional array and you are selecting all elements of axis "0" and "1", but only the first 3 elements (`[0,1,2]`)of axes "2".